# Подключение к устройству с 32 маской

Tags: lan

Доброго времени суток!

Ступил - каюсь. Сам понимаю но случайно на плате управления UPS выставил маску 255.255.255.255.... и сохранил. Устройство пингуется, но естественно веб морда теперь не работает. Есть ли возможность как то подключиться именно используя LAN?
А так буду искать провод и пытаться через Pytty, но провода нема потому и такой вопрос.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: /32 - это PPP/L2TP/прочее, чего УПС вряд ли умеет...